# Ember-Data ref. 11: Underscored Attribute Names - why?

Tags: ember-data

**Question 1**: Why needs ember-data revision 11 an underscored version of the attribute name?

**Question 2**: Is it a problem, if the attribute names are identical (without the underscore)?

**Ember-Link**: http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/

**The Model**

```
App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
    firstName: DS.attr('string'),
    lastName: DS.attr('string'),

    isPersonOfTheYear: DS.attr('boolean')
});
```

**The JSON**

```
{
   "person": {
        "first_name": "Barack",
        "last_name": "Obama",
        "is_person_of_the_year": true
    }
}
```

**The Mapping**

```
App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
    lastName: DS.attr('string')
});
DS.RESTAdapter.map('App.Person', {
    lastName: { key: 'lastNameOfPerson' }
});
```

Thanks to all responder! :)

Answer (score 3):

**Question1**: it's a convention in JS to have camel cased attributes.
For the JSON payload, see this [JSON Naming Convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543490/json-naming-convention)

Not sure to understand your 2nd question.

**Question2:**

If you want to keep your JSON format, you have 2 options explained in the code of the serializer https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/serializer.js#L58

- re-map them one-by-one using the adapter's `map` API
- You can determine the attribute name used in the serialized form by implementing `keyForAttributeName`

In your case you probably want to have your own serializer that inherits from the `RESTSerializer`. See https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/rest_serializer.js#L4

`keyForAttributeName` would simply return the string.

Comment: Hi Cyril, thanks for the hint. The point is: 
- I have a WCF application server side (camel case convention). 
- On client side JavaScript (camel case convention). 
- For Communication JSON (underscore convention is wished from Ember).
And a convention converting makes less sense for me. Is it therefore possible, to keep the camel case convention for the whole system without getting Trouble on Ember side?