# Json underscore or camelCase?

Tags: json

I've a question about the syntax of this json:

```
{
"trace_system": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Test"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Test2"
    }
  ]
}
```

is better put an underscore delimiter so: `trace_system` or using the camel case: `traceSystem`? What you suggest and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually prefer the `camelCase` convention, so your json should be:

```
{
"traceSystem": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Test"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Test2"
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't like very much the `_` 'cause for some tool as [Json2C#](http://json2csharp.com/) could create a wrong class and doesn't seems a good format anyway.

As suggested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543490/json-naming-convention) topic, there isn't a default standard that you can follow, this depends by your team. But as I said I suggest the `camelCase` convention.

Comment: It's purely a matter of preference. I prefer underscores.