# Confused over JSON creation practices while mapping to JsonProperty

Tags: java, json, jackson

JSON :

```
"ABCD": [  
  {  
    "xyz": 3,  
    "abc": 4,  
    "info": {  
      "MY_TITLE": "Hello World",  
      "MY_DESCRIPTION": "New to the world"  
    }
  }
  ...similar sub parts
]
```

In the case above, since `info` is another object in itself, the sub `string` are in upper case. My mapping to these in java goes on as :

```
@JsonProperty("xyz")
private Integer xyz;

@JsonProperty("abc")
private Integer abc;

@JsonProperty("MY_TITLE")
private String myTitle;

@JsonProperty("MY_DESCRIPTION")
private Long myDescription;
```

Need some documents and practices over the JSON creation and mapping the same on the java.

1. Is the JSON field naming convention inappropriate?

   OR/AND
2. Is the `JsonProperty` mapping incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the mapping seems inappropriate to me. What you should have is

```
// ...
@JsonProperty("xyz")
private Integer xyz;

@JsonProperty("abc")
private Integer abc;

@JsonProperty("info")
private MyInfoClass info;
// ...
```

then, the (separate) MyInfoClass :

```
public class MyInfoClass {

  @JsonProperty("MY_TITLE")
  private String myTitle;

  @JsonProperty("MY_DESCRIPTION")
  private Long myDescription;

  // getters, setters and so on
}
```

EDIT : as for the naming convention, I don't think there is a single widely accepted way, but the most common conventions I know of are camelCase and snake_case (both using non-capital letters). See this question for more info :
[JSON Naming Convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543490/json-naming-convention)

Comment: appreciate the idea of separating the classes, but for a broader project wouldn't it be different practice to follow camelCase in one class and snake_case in another?