# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value using Dictionary for valid JSON

Tags: ios, json, dictionary, swift3, xcode8

As the title states, I am receiving the "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" error. My JSON is valid, and the link can be found here: http://www.mocky.io/v2/5844d2801100001d140e6b91 .

The line of code that is giving me an issue is here:

```
let fighterDetails = dictionary["Fighters"]! as! [[String:AnyObject]]
```

At one point, I had all working code. I went back and re-structed my entire code as I decided to change the topic. I fixed all other errors, but I'm left with this at run-time.

[image]
[image: json receiver]

Comment: Clearly, `dictionary["Fighters"]` isn't a `[[String: AnyObject]]`

Comment: My professor has a similar line of code in his project example which is "        let customerDetails = dictionary["Customers"]! as! [[String:AnyObject]]" .  Customers is an object. His works. What's the difference?

Comment: Any time you use ! with external data, a little bunny dies and your program may crash.  Also, your JSON doesn't contain the string "Fighters" anywhere.  It does contain "Customers". Use conditional unwrapping

Comment: @Paulw11 - I had "Customers" instead of "Fighters" - Thank you very much!

Comment: @Paulw11, you just gave me the best laugh of the day with the dying bunny line. Thank you.

Comment: @Kevin, think of the `!` operator as the "crash if nil" operator, and avoid it like the plague until you **really** know what you're doing. It says "I know what I'm doing. This expression WILL resolve correctly. I stake my life on it." Unless you are 100% bet-your-program's-life-on-it-certain that the expression will evaluate successfully, don't use it.

Comment: Exactly what @DuncanC said. Your program crashes because you ASKED the compiler to write you a program that crashes when your assertions don't hold true (in this case, the assertion that `dictionary` contains a value of type `[[String: AnyValue]]` for the key `"Fighters"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When parsing remote JSON data, you should *never* use the `!` operator. Instead, use `guard` statements when unwrapping:

```
guard let fighterDetails = dictionary["Fighters"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] else {
    return []
}
```

And use `try?` instead of `try!`.

For the client developer, I recommend the usage of [SwiftLint](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint) to help you use better Swift practices. It would have detected the issue with `as!`.

For the server developer, I recommend to stick to one lettercase convention. [People tend to recommend camelCase when dealing with JSON keys](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5543490/1033581). i.e., you should rename "Fighters" to "fighters" to align with "name", "country", ... It may have avoided the issue of your missing key.

Comment: Wise words. In my opinion, `!` is "The `goto` of Swift" :-)

Comment: I'm waiting for the day Apple spares us from having to rely on `@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!` etc.

Comment: @Cœur Great feedback. Thank you for this.

Comment: I had to update the code you recommended to "guard let fighterDetails = dictionary["Fighters"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] else {
            return [:] as Any as! [Fighter]
        }  "

Can you explain the line "return [:] as Any as! [Fighter]" and why [:] wouldn't work as you recommended? The error it was giving was "contextual type Fighter cannot be used with dictionary literal"

Comment: @Kevin, please don't cast as Any. I've updated my answer: you can simply `return []`.

Comment: @Cœur - Thanks for your help and patience on the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the json url and there's no key "Fighters" in there.

Comment: Thanks so much! Good eye.