# Sserialize a JSON file using Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization

I have a JSON layout where the outer structure field is an array which everything else is par of it.

```
 {
   "attribute1":[
     {
       "@attribute2":"something",
       "attribute3":"something too",
       "attribute4":["something else"],
       "attribute5":{
           "what":"dont know",
           "carrier":"mailto:something@gmail.com"
        }
     }
   ]
```

}

I have the following POJO class:

```
public class Dataset {

     private List<object> attribute1;
     private String attribute2;
     private String[] attribute3;
     private Map<String, String> attribute4;
}
```

I have the accessors and getters methods defined too.

I instantiate the class `ObjectMapper` to use the `readValue` method to serialize the above file using the POJO class.

I have two issues:
   1. How I define `attribute1` so it contains everything that is embedded as array list?
   2. When I try to parse the `@attribute2` it errors out. I have to remove the `@` in order to pass this error. The file contains lot of attributes with `@` sign.

How do I handle that from the source file without modifying it?

Comment: Besides solving the error it is not recommended to use such signs for attributes [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25368854/4998135)
What you could do would be a custom serializer which does the same as the generic one jackson constructs but with removing all `@` and such things. So that it is a parsable JSON file.

Comment: I believe I will need to create Custom Type reference for List<Dataset>                                         
     
     TypeReference<List<Dataset>> mapType = new TypeReference<List<Dataset>>() {};
     List<Dataset> jsonToPersonList = objectMapper.readValue("location\data.json", mapType);

Is this a start.... I did modified but I getting an error cannot deserialize instance of ArrayList out of start_object token

Comment: So how in the first place the @ got define part of the json formatting. I have been told this is a json file. Im assuming should be able to read it... you are requesting to remove all the @ present in every field before commencing the parse. Is this correct?