# JSONAPI Type Naming Convention Camel Format Or Dash Format?

Tags: json-api

I'm building Product SKU API following the [JSONAPI](http://jsonapi.org/) specification.

Should the type be named as "product-skus" or "productSkus"?

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure it's not definitively specified for either JSONAPI or standard JSON (see: [JSON Naming Convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543490/json-naming-convention)), so you can make your own decision.

FWIW, the JSON API spec has examples with kebab-case (http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-compound-documents).

Answer (score 1):

The [JsonApiDotNetCore](https://json-api-dotnet.github.io/#/) framework is an implementation of [JSONAPI](http://jsonapi.org/) for .net core based projects. Found a [link](https://json-api-dotnet.github.io/#/models) in their documentation that uses hyphens.