# Webpack not parsing JSON

Tags: json, reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to load a JSON file into my ReactJS application, but any of the following methods I've tried the following:

Require:

```
const countries =require('../../json/countries.json');

// Also fails the exact same way with redundant parse call:
const countries = JSON.parse(require('../../json/countries.json'));
```

Importing using `json-loader`:

```
import countries from '../../json/countries.json';
```

Using the following loader in `loaders`

```
{
    test: /\.json$/,
    loader: 'json-loader'
}
```

The JSON loads, but fails to parse:

```
./src/app/json/countries.json
    Module build failed: SyntaxError: /src/app/json/countries.json: 
Unexpected token, expected ; (2:6)

  1 | {
> 2 |   "BD": "Bangladesh",
    |       ^
  3 |   "BE": "Belgium",
  4 |   "BF": "Burkina Faso",
  5 |   "BG": "Bulgaria",
```

The countries.json file is valid JSON downloaded from `http://country.io`, but it seems the quotes are causing an issue. But this is valid JSON being loaded by JavaScript, so it should work together seamlessly.

Any idea what the problem is?

**SOLVED**

I solved this issue by changing the `loader` directive into `use`:

```
let config = {
    module: {
        loaders: [
           ...
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'json-loader'
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: i don't understand, why are you trying to **parse** a `json`? it's already a javascript object, not a string.

Comment: I suggest the camelCase convention for JSON https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543490/json-naming-convention

Comment: I only tried parsing after I got an error without it. Something else is going on.

Comment: @SamDev This is a key/value map with two letter country codes. I don't see how the case of the keys is affecting anything.

Comment: @mwieczorek May be the naming conventions (variables should start with lower case letters)

Comment: @SamDev the naming convention is moot. Just to humor you, I changed "BD" to "bd" and of course, it did not matter. Please don't lecture me on naming conventions. Now if you have anything constructive to add...

Comment: @mwieczorek I'm just trying to help as for my knowledge, By the way I'm not professor that I'm lecturing you on stack overflow - It's better to solve your problem yourself

Answer (score 0):

You are loading a `json` file already, no need to parse it.
If it was a string you could parse it.
Here is a small example to demonstrate the difference:

```js
const json = {
  "BD": "Bangladesh",
  "BE": "Belgium",
  "BF": "Burkina Faso",
  "BG": "Bulgaria"
}

const strJson = `{
  "BD": "Bangladesh",
  "BE": "Belgium",
  "BF": "Burkina Faso",
  "BG": "Bulgaria"
}`

console.log('string parsed to a json',JSON.parse(strJson));
console.log('regular json',json);
```

Comment: Using it without parsing doesn't work either though: `const countries = require('../../json/countries.json');`

Comment: aw, you said _"The JSON loads, but fails to parse"_ so i thought no problems with loading it. what do you get after loading it? any errors?